# Como ajustar JInternalFrame y JFrame a la resolución de pantalla

Tags: java, eclipse

He realizado un aplicativo que me despliega varios JInternalFrame, lo hace ok , sucede que las interfaces son grandes entonces ocurre que al correr mi programa en una pantalla de 21 me muestra todo sin comerse nada de mi contenido, pero claro si la llevo a uno de 17 o 15, el tamaño de mi aplicativo se amolda a la resolución de la pantalla , pero los internals que me despliega el programa no se muestran completos estos continuan al tamaño que los diseñe, quisiera me orientaran, que debo hacer para que el tamaño de mis internals se amolden y en cualquier tamaño de ventana lo pueda ver bien. 
He estado implementando este codigo a los JInternalFrame pero no me funciona:

```
private Dimension dim;
dim=super.getToolkit().getScreenSize();
super.setSize(dim);
```

Comment: Utiliza `setPreferredSize` o setMaximum size.. igualmente los [JInternalFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) viven dentro de otro contenedor

Answer (score 1):

Yo maximizaría el jframe principal

```
external.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Las dimensiones de la pantalla las consigues en píxeles

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
```

y en función de esto anterior para los internos puedes crearte algunas fórmulas que aplicar comúnmente, por ejemplo yo algunas veces meto 2 a algo menos de un cuarto de pantalla

```
int ancho = (int)d.getWidth() / 2;
int alto = (int)d.getHeight() / 2;
jfinternal1.setSize(ancho, alto);
```

(con el 2 final en alto y ancho consigues el cuarto de pantalla)